# What is the underlying reason for a terminal that does not echo anymore?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am currently trying to use editline with python on linux, in place of readline. Overall it works, except that I get this behavior. This is verbatim from my terminal

```
   bash> python
   Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb 20 2015, 13:19:18) 
   [GCC 4.6.3] on linux3
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more  information. 
1  >>> 
2  >>> hello
3  >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
4
```

In 1, I press enter. it seems to work. in 2 I use an undefined name just to test. Note that in 3 I get a prompt *before* the traceback, and in 4 I have no prompt. In practice, the printing order is all screwed up. Similar things happen if I use print

```
 >>> print "hello"
 >>> hello
```

Now to the more important thing. When I quit the python executable with ^D or quit() I get this situation

```
 1 ^D>>> 
 2 bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> The program 'hello' can be found in the following packages:
    * hello
    * hello-debhelper
    Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
 3 bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash> bash>
```

in 1 I press control D. Note that the python prompt shows again. I get to the bash prompt. Now, in 2 if I press enter multiple times I get the prompt again and again. If I type "hello" followed by enter I don't get any echo of the characters. Same in 3.

If I use "reset" i restore the terminal to a sane state, but the point is that python, editline, or their interaction screws up the terminal somehow. I've seen this behavior also with ncurses when incorrectly deinitialized, but I am not sure about the underlying cause in terms of terminal settings that may have been altered.

I am trying to debug and fix the problem, so I would value any information about what exactly is happening at the terminal level that ruins it. Once I know which routine is doing the damage, I can trace the problem in more detail.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution. I already know a solution. I am looking to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Aparently `python/editline` combination are messing around with the output and probablay error streams.

My guess is that buffering mode is modified by somebody incorrectly to line-buffered mode (or full-buffered mode) for output stream.

Normally the error stream is in unbuffered mode. Probabaly thats why you are seeing the error message, but not the info (standard output)

When your terminating `python` kernel automatically flushes the content of the standard output buffer, so you see final messages as you described.

Well to figure out what exactly is happening you need to debug python interpretator.

Comment: do you know which specific function calls are used to set these ?

Comment: in `c` those are `setvbuf()`,  `_IOFBF` (full buffering), `_IOLBF` (line buffering) and `_IONBF` (no buffering) modes